# Controller Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'for' at line 12 column 8

Tags: controller-extension, visualforce-charting

I am gathering some data for a bar chart. I cannot see why it keeps yelling at me for the right curly bracket.

Error: Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'for' at line 12 column 8

What gives?

```
public class ChartController {

public class getData{
    List<Spend__c> SpendList = [
        SELECT id, Month__c, Spend__c 
        FROM Spend__c
        LIMIT 100];

    List<String> month = new List<String>();
    List<String> spend = new List<String>();

    for(Spend__c i : SpendList){
        month.add(i.Month__c);
        spend.add(i.Spend__c);
        }

    return month;
    return spend;

}


public class Spend {
    public Integer month {get;set;}
    public Integer spend {get;set;}
    Spend(Integer month, Integer spend) {
        this.month = month;
        this.spend = spend;

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your troubles start here:

```
public class getData{
```

Which I presume you meant to be some sort of method, based on its name:

```
public Spend[] getData() {
```

This is important, because only functions can have things like loops and return statements. In fact, I'd argue against having any executable code outside of functions, but some people like initializing their data using a default constructor and initializing statements. I disagree with this, because it makes it more challenging to find where something is initialized from if you mix constructors and inline initialization:

```
public class SomeClass {
    String[] list1 = new String[0];
    Integer[] list2 = new Integer[] { 3, 5, 7 };
    Decimal[] list3;
    // Some time later...
    public SomeClass() {
        list3 = new Decimal[0];
    }
}
```

You should use *either* constructors or inline initializers, but not both.

Finally, you can only have one return value, so you probably meant to return a list of Spend (`Spend[]`):

```
public Spend[] getData() {
    Spend[] results = new Spend[0];

    for(Spend__c i : [
        SELECT id, Month__c, Spend__c 
        FROM Spend__c
        LIMIT 100]){
        results.add(new Spend(i.Month__c, i.Spend__c));
    }

    return results;
}
```

You'll need to modify your Visualforce code accordingly, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is declaring a nested class:

```
public class getData{
```

and `for` loops can only appear inside methods or in the constructor of a class.

Perhaps you intend `getData` to be a method that returns the `month` or `spend`:

```
public List<String> getData() {
    ...
    return month;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your class as its laid out. You should read up on OO fundamentals like context and scope.

But, the answer you are looking for is... you must execute your loop inside a method or constructor like so:

```
public List<List<String>> getData() {
  for(Spend__c i : SpendList){
    month.add(i.Month__c);
    spend.add(i.Spend__c);
  }
  return new List<List<String>>{month,spend};
}
```